Review for the series of A Course In Analysis by Niels Jacob
So I'm now self studying multivariable calculus and one of my friends mentioned the series titled "A Course In Analysis by Niels Jacob" (I don't know where else to ask this, sorry if this does not belong to the forum); however, I can't really find any reviews or comments related to that. From the table of contents, it ranges from basic single variable calculus all the way to pretty advanced stuff like lie groups. Has anyone read any of the books in the series and can leave a comment? Thanks in advance!
Table of Contents

There is an MAA review.
